# DocuSign JWT Grant flow Consent_Required for blanket consent

Tags: docusignapi

We have implemented `JWT grant flow` and provided `blanket consent` for `integration key` but when impersonating registered and active user under this account getting `consent required` error.

- We have SSO enabled
- All users are with same domain
- Blanket consent provided with `impersonation signature` scope

Here how I am trying to get access token using DocuSign's C# SDK for impersonated user:

```
string BaseUrl = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi";
string oAuthBasePath = "account-d.docusign.com";
var apiClient = new DocuSign.eSign.Client.ApiClient(BaseUrl, oAuthBasePath, null);

    //Get access token using admin account
    OAuth.OAuthToken tokenInfo = apiClient.RequestJWTUserToken(Integration_Client_Key, UserId, oAuthBasePath, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(RSAPrivateKey), 1, Scopes);
    OAuth.UserInfo userInfo = apiClient.GetUserInfo(tokenInfo.access_token);
    var account = userInfo.Accounts.FirstOrDefault(a => a.AccountId == AccountId);
    apiClient = new ApiClient(BaseUrl, oAuthBasePath, null);
    
    //Get user's UserId(GUID) to impersonate
    var impersonateUserId = await SignatureHandlerEmailId(signatureHandlerEmailId, tokenInfo.access_token);
    
    //Get access token using impersonate userId
    tokenInfo = apiClient.RequestJWTUserToken(Integration_Client_Key, impersonateUserId, oAuthBasePath, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(RSAPrivateKey), 1, Scopes);
    userInfo = apiClient.GetUserInfo(tokenInfo.access_token); //-- Here exception getting thrown for consent
```

Is there any wrong `url` I am passing or anything additional `configuration` need to do before sending request?

Comment: WELCOME to StackOverflow!! Please check (accept) the best answer for each of your questions. Thank you, it make a BIG difference!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have SSO and a claimed domain for demo.docusign.net?

You're using the demo IdP (account-d.docusign.com). It is a completely different IdP than the production IdP, account.docusign.com.

Since you're using account-d.docusign.com, you need to claim the email domain for it using the demo.docusign.net org admin tool.

### Added: checking your claimed email domains

This info is available via the **Domains** section of the DocuSign organization administration tool.

See the [docs](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/org-admin-guide-domains).

### Added some more

You can also programmatically get a list of the organization's claimed domains via the Org Admin API method [ReservedDomains:getReservedDomains](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/admin-api/reference/ReservedDomains/ReservedDomains/getReservedDomains)

Comment: How I can ensure/check whether or not domain has claimed against specific environment demo/production?

Comment: Is there any other way to ensure domain not claimed rather than looking at Domain section of DocuSign organization administration tool?

Comment: Larry K am I missing something for API call configuration or doing something wrong in code because we confirmed on domain claim thing. The domain has claimed and in active state

Comment: Please open a new question or email go-liveATATdocusign.com if you're still having a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Another condition will be to claim a domain. 
You can refer to this how-to [guide](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/org-admin-guide-domains)

Also this blog post has a great [info](https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/oauth-jwt-granting-consent)